# Includegraphics doesnt show graphic if using bounding box

Tags: graphics, bounding-box

as the title says... I dont really know what's the problem, tried with different formats of figures (`eps`, `pdf`, `jpg`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
         \fbox{\includegraphics[bb= 1 150 600 700,scale=0.5]{tiger}}
\end{document}
```

the picture should be `tiger.eps`
this is what i get:

[image]

if I use following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
         \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{tiger}}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

using miktex 2.9 + Texmaker 5.0.2 but tried LyX 2.2.3 with the same result, tried different numbers and units for the `bb=` argument without success, hope someone can help

Edit: thanks for the answers, yeah i use pdflatex... i actually am a LyX user and use bb just because the LyX uses it and there is no option to use to viewport instead.. however if i use ps2pdf instead of pdflatex, it works.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: If you are using pdflatex (you do not say) do not use the bb key, use trim= or viewport= if you want to clip to a specific part of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, according to [this bug report](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7910) on The LyX Source and Ticket Browser, the original problem (no images in final PDF when using 'Clip to bounding box') is caused by one of the packages in the latest LaTeX version dropping full support for `\includegraphics` 'bb' option.

Following the above link, one will find a patch for recompiling Lyx 2.2.3, essentially modifying LyX's BoundingBox feature internally by replacing 'bb' with 'viewport'.

If you cannot recompile LyX, you will have to wait a little longer for version 2.2.4: according to [LyX statusreport for 2.2.x](http://www.lyx.org/trac/browser/lyxgit/status.22x?rev=2.2.x) on The LyX Source and Ticket Browser, the problem should be fixed (look for "Fix PDF output of clipped graphics with recent graphics package (bug 7910)").

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will use the bug tracker of lyx now too :)

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want to use option `bb`?

Examples:

- EPS with LaTeX + dvips

  Package `graphics` already can read the `%%BoundingBox` comment at the top of the file. Option `bb` is not needed.
- PDF with pdfLaTeX

  The pdfTeX compiler in PDF mode reads the MediaBox (or optionally other boxes)   of the image file. There is no need for option `bb`.

  Therefore, driver `pdftex.def` issues a warning and uses option `viewport` instead.
- PDF with XeLaTeX

  Also, XeTeX reads the MediaBox of the PDF image.

The image was displayed with all these cases. However, the position of the
image was always wrong, because the bounding box in setting `bb=1 150 600 700`
is wrong, the bounding box of ghostscript`s`tiger.eps` is:

```
%%BoundingBox: 17 171 567 739
```

In most cases, option `bb` is not needed. Option `bb` has the disadvantages:

- The user has to investigate to get the correct values.
- If an image change alters the bounding box, then the numbers needs to be updated in the TeX file.

If you want to display only a part of the image, use option `viewport` or `trim`. Option `clip` hides the areas outside the selected area.

Comment: so whats with .jpg files? why do they not work?

Comment: @A.Ston They work, e.g. with `pdflatex`. Again, pdfTeX already knows the size of the `.jpg` image and option `bb` does not make sense.

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid using `bb` and use `viewport` (and `clip`) or `trim` instead. Here are some examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{tiger}}
%
\fbox{\includegraphics[viewport=1 150 600 700,scale=0.1]{tiger}}
%
\fbox{\includegraphics[viewport=1 150 600 700,clip,scale=0.1]{tiger}}
%
\fbox{\includegraphics[trim=1 150 0 0,scale=0.1]{tiger}}

\end{document}
```

With `viewport` you specify coordinates relative to the `b`ounding `b`ox origin (usually the lower left corner). With `trim` you specify what needs to be removed from each side.